# How to access .env variable in config.json file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, config

I'm working on a react app and this is my .env.production file:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://192.168.0.16:30/api
```

And this is my .env.development file:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:13748/api
```

How can I access to REACT_APP_API_URL in config.json file like this:

```
{
  "apiUrl": "this is where I want to access to REACT_APP_API_URL variable"
}
```

Comment: Try to add this - `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL`

Comment: @ravibagul91 it doesn't work in config.json file!

Comment: How you are using config.json file in your components?

Comment: How are you reading your .env files? The most commonly used solution is this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv